# Docker compose not working inside zsh shell in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, docker-compose, pycharm, zsh, oh-my-zsh

When I want to use `docker-compose` inside Intellij I get this error:

`[29319] Cannot open self /home/user/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/bin/jetbrains-toolbox or archive /home/user/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/bin/jetbrains-toolbox.pkg`

[image]

When I use it in my terminal it works. Only when I use it inside Intellij (and Pycharm) it does not work. When I used bash terminal in Intellij it works.

I am trying to figure out why this happens. But I don't have a clue.

Who knows how to get docker-compose working with zsh and Intellij?

Comment: Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-240605

Comment: Or even this one: 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-52819 (which I believe relates to the ticket above)

Answer (score 0):

Go To Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Docker -> Tools

Set Docker Compose executable to correct value. There should be a symlink to a `docker-compose-v1` in /usr/local/bin/docker. That's what you're looking for. Select the `docker-compose-v1` symlink and it will populate the path to docker-compose. From there, restart your IDE and docker-compose should work inside IntelliJ/WebStorm/PHPStorm